# Shared Folders in QEMU-KVM with Virt Machine but without net

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm running Kubuntu 16.10 as host and windows 10 as guest.

The guest system should be a sandbox without internet so I removed the network card.

There is an option in virt-manager to add a filesystem (instead of a storage device). I added a path, but how can i get access in the guest system (Windows)?

I can't find any documentation of acces in the guest windows.

I am looking for a definition which the path of the host assigns a letter or directory in the guest-windows.

I don't want to use samba with virtual-nic this i tried and is working.

The second option would be a set-up with nic but disabled internet.

many thanks for your help

andy

Comment: Nobody knows about it?

Comment: +1 Also, can you please share more details on how you got it to work with net in the first place? No docs to be found!